# merge tool for salesforce profiles - can it be done?

Tags: git, version-control, sourcecontrol

I am implementing git for our salesforce team.  I've got some slick python scripts that retrieve/deploy to the cloud and it's all good except for a few situations which are pretty painful.  I hope there is a solution I haven't thought of.

Here's one scenario.  Admin #1 creates her branch and checks in a change which is a new text field.  Admin #2 creates his branch and checks in a change which is a (different) new text field (on the same object).

When the second of those two branches is merged into the integration branch, the two new fields conflict, most painfully on every profile.

Here's how kdiff tries to help me merge one profile.

[image]

It wants to create permissions to one custom field with two labels.  Yikes.  There's no way to get two blocks, one for each new field.

And here's how meld does it.

[image]

Again I can't get two blocks.  The profile XML is valid this time but I can pick a label from one and fullName from the other, haha.

We have many dozens of profiles and this scenario is not that far fetched.  My best thought right now is not manage profiles but that would be sad.

Comment: I'm working on a tool that splits the XML files into something more git-friendly, but it'll be like a month before it's ready :(

Comment: @sfdcfox What are your plans for this tool? Is it going to be open-source?

Comment: @AlanMorey Yes, while I am working on some closed-source stuff, I feel that such an incredibly simple tool would help fill a void for virtually every organization that uses the API... it'd be almost irresponsible not to share.